# Module for building swing tables

Tags: java, collections, jdbc

I have a module that builds swing tables based on an `Object[][]`, then I have another module that queries an SQLite database and returns a `ResultSet`.

I have written a method that converts the [`ResultSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) to an `ArrayList<Object[]>` first, then further into an `Object[][]`. The reason I do it this way is because you cannot get the row count from the `ResultSet` without iterating over it.

I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to build my `Object[][]` from the `ResultSet` without having to iterate over the data twice.

Here is the method that performs the conversion:

```
public Object[][] executeQuery(String query) throws SQLException{
    ResultSet rs = getResultSet(query);
    ResultSetMetaData rsMetaData = rs.getMetaData();
    int columnCount = rsMetaData.getColumnCount();
    ArrayList<Object[]> result = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
    Object[] header = new Object[columnCount];
    for (int i=1; i <= columnCount; ++i){
        Object label = rsMetaData.getColumnLabel(i);
        header[i-1] = label;
    }
    while (rs.next()){
        Object[] str = new Object[columnCount];
        for (int i=1; i <= columnCount; ++i){
            Object obj = rs.getObject(i);
            str[i-1] = obj;
        }
        result.add(str);
    }
    int resultLength = result.size();
    Object[][] finalResult = new Object[resultLength][columnCount];
    finalResult[0] = header;
    for(int i=1;i<resultLength;++i){
        Object[] row = result.get(i);
        finalResult[i] = row;
    }
    return finalResult;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, you could just call the [`toArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29) method of your list to transform the list into an array. Or even better, you could make the table model use a `List<Object[]>` rather than an `Object[][]`, which would avoid the unnecessary conversion.

Comment: +1 `toArray` does the same thing as the posted code, but better. You can actually get the row count by doing another query first, but it's definitely not worth it.

Comment: Yeah, I looked at using another query to get the row count, but I came to the same conclusion.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with *@JB Nizet*, some other notes about the current implementation:

1. Use the `List` interface as reference type instead of the implementation type. I mean change

   ```
   ArrayList<Object[]> result = ...
   ```

   to

   ```
   List<Object[]> result = ...
   ```

   [Type List vs type ArrayList in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279030/type-list-vs-type-arraylist-in-java)
2. I'd change the indexing in the for loops:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; ++i) {
       final Object label = metaData.getColumnLabel(i + 1);
       header[i] = label;
   }
   ```

   I think `for (i = 0; i < max; i++)` style looks more familiar for most programmers.
3. I'd extract out a `getHeaders` method:

   ```
   private Object[] getHeaders(final ResultSetMetaData metaData) throws SQLException {
       final int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
       final Object[] header = new Object[columnCount];
       for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; ++i) {
           final Object label = metaData.getColumnLabel(i + 1);
           header[i] = label;
       }
       return header;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a bug where we lose the first record of data

> ```
> int resultLength = result.size();
> ```

should be `int resultLength = result.size()+1;`

> ```
> Object[] row = result.get(i);
> ```

should be `Object[] row = result.get(i-1);`

Here's the fix:

```
int resultLength = result.size()+1;
Object[][] finalResult = new Object[resultLength][columnCount];
finalResult[0] = header;
for(int i=1;i<resultLength;++i){
    Object[] row = result.get(i-1);
    finalResult[i] = row;
}
```

Comment: ResultSet is 1 based.